# Android camera supported picture sizes in 1.6

Tags: android, camera, resolution, image

To retrieve the Android camera size I've used the following code:

```
camera=Camera.open();
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
List sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
for (int i=0;i<sizes.size();i++){
    Log.i("PictureSize", "Supported Size: " +sizes.get(i));         
}
```

But `getSupportedPictureSizes()` doesn't work in android 1.6. How to retrieve the maximum supported size of the camera in some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method is only supported in API version >= 8. 
Check out this links:

[Android backward code compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4873827/android-backward-code-compatibility)

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html

Comment: That totally doesn't answer the OP's question. The question is "how do I get this size in a different way"? Besides, the docs say it's API version 5 and above, not sure why the linked question says 8.